# AVG ( column1 ) while DISTINCT( column2 )

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the average of one column while using other column as distinct, and i cant use group by because it'll affects some other data is there any way to do this with out group by

```
id      name      price
----------------------
1       name1     200
2       name2     200
3       name3     100
3       name3     100
```

I want the average of column price but there is duplicate rows, so i can't just write AVG( price ) and also i cant use distinct on price, instead i want to use distinct on id without using groupby

```
AVG( DISTINCT price)
```

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected result.

Comment: Your question, at the time of writing this comment, is totally unanswerable.  Please show us sample input along the expected output.

Comment: I have one table which have one column price , And i want to use distinct because there can be duplicate datas,  obviously i cant use distinct on price column,  instead i want to use id column as distinct

Comment: @RanjithM basically you want get average price of entire table with id column. is that

Comment: For same ids which price you need in average, greatest price or lowest price ? Like for id 3 price 100 or 200 ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the average price from whole table and on distinct ids then first you need to exclude the duplicate data based on same id, Following query will pick the single row per id with highest price, For e.g. considering your sample data for id 3 there are 3 prices 100 and 200. It will take 200 for id 3 if you want to pick the lowest price then change `a.price < b.price` to `a.price > b.price`

```
select distinct a.*
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.id = b.id
and a.price < b.price
where b.id is null;
```

Once you have distinct data then you can apply `avg()`

```
select avg(price)
from (select distinct a.*
      from table1 a
      left join table1 b on a.id = b.id
      and a.price < b.price
      where b.id is null
) t;
```

Or

```
select  avg(a.price)
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.id = b.id
and a.price < b.price
where b.id is null;
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/WKGD46278) there is some formatting issue in rextester so here is the [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a82f4f/8)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(DISTINCT price) FROM tableName;
```

Comment: read the title 'AVG ( column1 ) while DISTINCT( column2 )' avg and other column there